# Prometheus dashboard is not updating state of website

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I've manually stopped this site and prometheus is giving probe_success 0 (fail) which means website is not running but the state is still up, its not getting updated. what should i do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "UP" in the Prometheus > Status > Targets page means that the target is being scraped, in other words, it means that all Blackbox metrics for that target were successfully scraped. The fact that the web site isn't running is reflected in the probe_success=0 metric, as you have noticed.

Comment: then how to show that on dasboard that website is down?

Comment: Look at the "probe_success" metric (0 = Down, 1 = Up).